# What counters the outlining effect of the Glitterdust spell?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-1e, magic-items, invisibility

Aside from the wondrous item called [Dust of Darkness](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/c-d/dust-of-darkness/) how can someone counter the outlining effect of [Glitterdust](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/g/glitterdust/)?

Comment: Are you only looking for solutions that specifically counter the outlining effect of *Glitterdust* but not the blinding effect, as *dust of darkness* does? Or would effects that entirely counter *Glitterdust* be valid?

Comment: If by countering the overall spell you also counter the outlining, that's accepted too. But i'm not looking for an answer like Dispel Magic, that would be obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I smell a spell coming from previous versions of DnD that has been poorly ported, but here goes:

**Glitterdust** is a conjuration (creation) spell - it actually create real, physical dust which vanishes when the spell expires - but expressedly states that the dust *can not be removed*; so we can throw out all attempts to move it - no flooding, no washing, no blowing.

You don't want to get the **Dispel Magic** answer because it would be obvious, but it *is* the most straightforward and less bothersome way to do it after **Dust of Darkness**.

Interestingly enough, **Glitterdust** does not possess the [Light] tag as descriptor. So the next best solution is to obfuscate lines of sight. **Darkness** and **Deeper Darkness** *could* bring the light level to darkness or supernatural darkness in the spell area, giving you concealment. Effectively, since the line of sight is blocked, the outlining effect is moot. Same goes for **Cloud of Smoke** and the likes. You can achieve this effect via the spells or some magical items that replicate those effects.

Second best option is *not to be invisible*. And by that, I mean something like **Blink**, which makes you alternate between Material and Ethereal Plane. When on the Ethereal Plane, you're on an entirely different Plane, not just invisible, so *Glitterdust* outlining effect does not apply - though I'd argue the blinding part is still in effect if someone managed to pin it on you while on the Material plane.

I could go and enumerate a few options that are not what you're looking for, such as **Stone Wall**, which technically block lines of sight. But to sum it up, you can either hide the dust (by RAW) by varying the level of light or be one step above invisible.

Other than the direct spells intended to counter it, you're out of luck to counter it *directly*.